# Do monad transformers apply to getting JSON from services?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, monads, monad-transformers

I have a Play! 2 for Scala application that needs to retrieve some data in JSON format from an external service.

The Play! framework allows to make HTTP requests asynchronously by wrapping the response in a [Promise](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaWS). `Promise` is a monad that wraps a value that will be available in the future.

This is fine, but in my case what I get from the web service is a JSON string. I have to parse it and the parsing might fail. So I have to wrap whatever I get into an `Option`. The result is that many of my methods are returning `Promise[Option[Whatever]]`. That is, a value of type `Whatever` that will be, maybe, available later.

Now whenever I have to operate over such a value I need to `map` it twice. I was thinking of handling this in the following way:

- creating a new type, say `Hope[A]`, that wraps a `Promise[Option[A]]`
- defining the relevant methods like `map` (or maybe I should use `foreach` and inherit from some collection trait?) and `flatten`
- provide an implicit converter between `Promise[Option[A]]` and `Hope[A]`.

It is easy to define `map` - the composition of two functors is again a functor - and `flatten` can be done explicitly in this case, or whenever composing a monad with `Option`.

**But** it is my limited understanding that I do not need to reinvent this stuff: monad transformer exist for exactly this case. Or, well, so I think - I have never used a monad tranformer - and this is the point of the question:

> Can monad tranformers be used in this situation? How would I go about actually using them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the Scalaz library's `OptionT` transformer, you should be able to turn values of type `Promise[Option[A]]` into values of type `OptionT[Promise, A]`.

Using Scalaz 7:

```
import scalaz.OptionT._
val x: OptionT[Promise, Int] = optionT(Promise.pure(Some(123)))
```

To use this value, for example to call `map` or `flatMap` on it, you will need to provide an appropriate typeclass for `Promise` (`Functor` for `map`, `Monad` for `flatMap`).

Since `Promise` is monadic, it should be possible to provide an instance of `Monad[Promise]`. (You'll get `Functor` and `Applicative` for free, because the typeclasses form an inheritance hierarchy.)  For example (note: I've not tested this!):

```
implicit val promiseMonad = new Monad[Promise] {
  def point[A](a: => A): Promise[A] = Promise.pure(a)
  def bind[A, B](fa: Promise[A])(f: A => Promise[B]): Promise[B] = fa flatMap f
}
```

As a simple example, you can now use `map` on the `OptionT[Promise, A]`, to apply a function of type `A => B` to the value inside:

```
def foo[A, B](x: OptionT[Promise, A], f: A => B): OptionT[Promise, B] = x map f
```

To retrieve the underlying `Promise[Option[A]]` value from an `OptionT[Promise, A]`, call the `run` method.

```
def bar[A, B](x: Promise[Option[A]], f: A => B): Promise[Option[B]] =
  optionT(x).map(f).run
```

You will gain more benefit from using monad transformers when you can compose several operations of compatible types, preserving the `OptionT[Promise, _]` type between operations and retrieving the underlying value at the end.

To compose operations in a for-comprehension, you will need functions of type `A => OptionT[Promise, B]`.

Comment: I have tried it and everything works fine in my application. There is only one odd thing: if I introduce a type alias `type Hope[A] = Promise[Option[A]]` to simplify the return type of my functions, I get a compile-time error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size`. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: @Andrea: If you use an explicit type parameter with `optionT` the error should go away. It looks like a compiler bug and if you have the time it might be worth checking [the issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) or asking a follow-up question here.

Answer (score 1):

-- removed --

edit:

Okay, you can simply use the `scalaz.OptionT` here:

```
val x = optionT(Promise { /* api call */ some("""{ "foo": "bar" }""") })
val mapped = x.map(Json.parse).run // run return the resulting Promise[Option[T]]
```

Comment: Well, in writing `x map (_ * 2)` instead of your four lines. Now, in this little example it may be of little value, but in more complex cases I think it may make matters more clear.

Comment: This for-comprehension will not compile because `x` and `opt` are not of compatible types. You would need to nest two for-comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted the other answer, though, as it is more detailed, and as I said I am new to monad trasformers.

Comment: I'm absolutely fine with that ;-)