# Future[Option] in Scala for-comprehensions

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I have two functions which return Futures. I'm trying to feed a modified result from first function into the other using a for-yield comprehension.

This approach works:

```
  val schoolFuture = for {
    ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)
    sid = ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId)
    s <- schoolStore.getSchool(sid.get) if sid.isDefined
  } yield s
```

However I'm not happy with having the "if" in there, it seems that I should be able to use a map instead.

But when I try with a map:

```
  val schoolFuture: Future[Option[School]] = for {
    ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)
    sid = ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId)
    s <- sid.map(schoolStore.getSchool(_))
  } yield s
```

I get a compile error:

```
[error]  found   : Option[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[School]]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[School]]
[error]         s <- sid.map(schoolStore.getSchool(_))
```

I've played around with a few variations, but haven't found anything attractive that works. Can anyone suggest a nicer comprehension and/or explain what's wrong with my 2nd example?

Here is a minimal but complete runnable example with Scala 2.10:

```
import concurrent.{Future, Promise}

case class User(userId: Int)
case class UserDetails(userId: Int, schoolId: Option[Int])
case class School(schoolId: Int, name: String)

trait Error

class UserStore {
  def getUserDetails(userId: Int): Future[Either[Error, UserDetails]] = Promise.successful(Right(UserDetails(1, Some(1)))).future
}

class SchoolStore {
  def getSchool(schoolId: Int): Future[Option[School]] = Promise.successful(Option(School(1, "Big School"))).future
}

object Demo {
  import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val userStore = new UserStore
  val schoolStore = new SchoolStore

  val user = User(1)

  val schoolFuture: Future[Option[School]] = for {
    ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)
    sid = ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId)
    s <- sid.map(schoolStore.getSchool(_))
  } yield s
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245987/do-monads-transformers-apply-to-getting-json-from-services/12248618#12248618) to a similar question about `Promise[Option[A]]` might help. Just substitute `Future` for `Promise`.

I'm inferring the following types for `getUserDetails` and `getSchool` from your question:

```
getUserDetails: UserID => Future[Either[??, UserDetails]]
getSchool: SchoolID => Future[Option[School]]
```

Since you ignore the failure value from the `Either`, transforming it to an `Option` instead, you effectively have two values of type `A => Future[Option[B]]`.

Once you've got a `Monad` instance for `Future` (there may be one in [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), or you could write your own as in the answer I linked), applying the `OptionT` transformer to your problem would look something like this:

```
for {
  ud  <- optionT(getUserDetails(user.userID) map (_.right.toOption))
  sid <- optionT(Future.successful(ud.schoolID))
  s   <- optionT(getSchool(sid))
} yield s
```

Note that, to keep the types compatible, `ud.schoolID` is wrapped in an (already completed) Future.

The result of this for-comprehension would have type `OptionT[Future, SchoolID]`. You can extract a value of type `Future[Option[SchoolID]]` with the transformer's `run` method.

Comment: Admittedly scalaz scares me a bit, I still have a ways to go on the learning curve. This solves the issue about as well as I think it can be. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the link to the scalaz-contrib library is broken

Comment: You don't need `scalaz-contrib anymore`, since future instances for Monad are now provided by scalaz itself by mixing the `FutureInstances` trait.

Answer (score 22):

(Edited to give a correct answer!)

The key here is that `Future` and `Option` *don't compose inside `for`* because there aren't the correct `flatMap` signatures.  As a reminder, for desugars like so:

```
for ( x0 <- c0; w1 = d1; x1 <- c1 if p1; ... ; xN <- cN) yield f
c0.flatMap{ x0 => 
  val w1 = d1
  c1.filter(x1 => p1).flatMap{ x1 =>
    ... cN.map(xN => f) ... 
  }
}
```

(where any `if` statement throws a `filter` into the chain--I've given just one example--and the equals statements just set variables before the next part of the chain).  Since you can only `flatMap` other `Future`s, every statement `c0`, `c1`, ... except the last had better produce a `Future`.

Now, `getUserDetails` and `getSchool` both produce `Futures`, but `sid` is an `Option`, so we can't put it on the right-hand side of a `<-`.  Unfortunately, there's no clean out-of-the-box way to do this.  If `o` is an option, we can

```
o.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(Future.failed(new Exception))
```

to turn an `Option` into an already-completed `Future`.  So

```
for {
  ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)  // RHS is a Future[Either[...]]
  sid = ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId)  // RHS is an Option[Int]
  fid <- sid.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(Future.failed(new Exception))  // RHS is Future[Int]
  s <- schoolStore.getSchool(fid)
} yield s
```

will do the trick.  Is that better than what you've got?  Doubtful.  But if you

```
implicit class OptionIsFuture[A](val option: Option[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def future = option.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(Future.failed(new Exception))
}
```

then suddenly the for-comprehension looks reasonable again:

```
for {
  ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)
  sid <- ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId).future
  s <- schoolStore.getSchool(sid)
} yield s
```

Is this the best way to write this code?  Probably not; it relies upon converting a `None` into an exception simply because you don't know what else to do at that point.  This is hard to work around because of the design decisions of `Future`; I'd suggest that your original code (which invokes a filter) is at least as good of a way to do it.

Comment: This is giving me a compile error.

found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[com.authorpub.userservice.School]]

required: Option[?]
s <- schoolStore.getSchool(sid)

Comment: Can you explain what all your types are?  It's a little hard to tell given that you haven't posted full working code.  What is a future and what is an option in your working code?  You can get Scala 2.10 to print out the type of an expression if you do this: `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._; def typeme[A: TypeTag](a: A) = { println(implicitly[TypeTag[A]]); a }` and then wrap the expression in `typeme`, e.g. `sid = typeme(ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolID))`.

Comment: Someone downvoted without comment.  This isn't very useful.  What's wrong with the answer as it stands now?

Comment: I prefer the answer from Ben James. Although Scalaz, Monads and all this stuff scares many people, in fact these concepts are very simple. Scalaz already has all the abstractions needed to solve the problem. On the contrary, this answer introduces a new concept `OptionIsFuture` which I suppose to be similar to a monad transformer.

Answer (score 8):

What behavior would you like to occur in the case that the `Option[School]` is `None`? Would you like the Future to fail? With what kind of exception? Would you like it to never complete? (That sounds like a bad idea).

Anyways, the `if` clause in a for-expression desugars to a call to the `filter` method. The contract on `Future#filter`is thus:

> If the current future contains a value which satisfies the predicate,
>   the new future will also hold that value. Otherwise, the resulting
>   future will fail with a NoSuchElementException.

But wait:

```
scala> None.get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

As you can see, None.get returns the exact same thing.

Thus, getting rid of the `if sid.isDefined` should work, and this should return a reasonable result:

```
  val schoolFuture = for {
    ud <- userStore.getUserDetails(user.userId)
    sid = ud.right.toOption.flatMap(_.schoolId)
    s <- schoolStore.getSchool(sid.get)
  } yield s
```

Keep in mind that the result of `schoolFuture` can be in instance of `scala.util.Failure[NoSuchElementException]`. But you haven't described what other behavior you'd like.

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't need Scalaz ;) *ducks*

Answer (score 3):

We've made small wrapper on Future[Option[T]] which acts like one monad (nobody even checked none of monad laws, but there is map, flatMap, foreach, filter and so on) - [MaybeLater](https://github.com/escalate42/MaybeLater). It behaves much more than an async option.

There are a lot of smelly code there, but maybe it will be usefull at least as an example.
BTW: there are a lot of open questions([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/scala-sips/VRlDgX4yFKE/discussion) for ex.)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use  `https://github.com/qifun/stateless-future` or `https://github.com/scala/async` to do `A-Normal-Form` transform.