# Future[Option[Boolean]] in a for comprehension.. Simple right?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Suppose I have:

```
val res:Future[Option[Boolean]] = Future(Some(true))
```

and I can do:

```
res.map(opt => opt.map(r => print(!r)))
```

I guess the for comprehension for this would be:

```
for {
   opt <- res
   r <- opt
} yield (print(!r))
```

***but this does not work!*** I get an error ie:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Option[Unit]
required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
r <- opt
```

**How do I use a Future[Option[Boolean]] in a for comprehension to extract or convert the Boolean?**

**Note:** this is a simplification of the problem I have at the moment with many Future[Option[Boolean]] variables that I would like to use **together** in a for comprehension.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385633/futureoption-in-scala-for-comprehensions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A for-comprehension really makes this look like it should all work, doesn't it?  But let's think about what you're asking for.

First, note that `for` un-nests:

```
for {xs <- List(List(5)); x <- xs} yield x
```

produces

```
List(5)
```

Now, without even getting into the type signatures or desugaring, we can think about replacing `List` with some arbitrary type `T`, and we'll call the contained type `A`:

```
for { xs <- T(T(a: A)); x <- xs } yield x
```

and we should get a

```
T[A]
```

back (presumably the one we put in, but the types don't actually promise us that).

Okay, but what about

```
for { xs <- T(U(a: A)); x <- xs } yield x
```

?  This is strictly more general than the case where the two things have the same nesting.  Well, if `T` and `U` both have a common supertype `S`, then we can just view the whole thing as `S(S(a: A))`, so we'll at least get an `S` back.  But what about in the general case?

The bottom line is that *it depends*.  For example, let's consider the case where `T=Future`, `U=Option`.  We have the following possibilities:

```
Success(Some(a))
Success(None)
Failure(t: Throwable)
```

Now, can we come up with any coherent policy for unwrapping?  If we unwrap into a `Future`, then what `A` do you use for the `Success(None)` case?  You don't have one available to return.  Likewise, if you try to vanquish the outer `Future`, how do you know, without explicitly stating it somehow to the compiler, that `Failure` should be mapped to `None` (if indeed it should--maybe it should go to a default!).

So the bottom line is that you just *can't* do this correctly in general without specifying what is supposed to happen for every pair `T[U[_]]`.  (I encourage the interested reader to peruse tutorials on [monads](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2007/09/monads-are-elephants-part-1.html) and [monad transformers](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2011/07/monad-transformers-in-scala.html).)

There is a way out, though: if you can explicitly turn your `U` into a `T`, or your `T` into your `U`, you can take advantage of the unwrapping capability.  It's pretty easy to turn an `Option` into a `Future` , so the easiest solution is

```
for { opt <- res; r <- Future(opt.get) } yield r
```

(where just let the exception get thrown on `none.get`).  Alternatively, you can turn the `Future` into an `Option` with the slightly ugly

```
for { opt <- res.value.flatMap(_.toOption); r <- opt } yield r
```

Answer (score 8):

Equivalent code for

```
for {
   opt <- res
   r <- opt
} yield (print(!r))
```

is not

```
res.map(opt => opt.map(r => print(!r)))
```

but

```
res.flatMap(opt => opt.map(r => print(!r)))
```

And it makes no sense in this case.

For the chain of `map`s you could use nested `for-comprehensions`

```
for { opt <- res }
  for { r <- opt }
    print(!r)
```

But `map` looks better.

Comment: `foreach` is the canonical method to use for side effects.  `map` makes it look like you expect some sort of informative return value. I grant that the OP asked for a map, but it's worth pointing out. Good call on the nested fors, though!

Answer (score 5):

Well, `for` comprehensions are deceiving in the way they look. Your for-comprehension expands to:

```
res.flatMap(opt => opt.map(r => print(!r))
```

Which is obviously wrong as `flatMap` expects a return type of `Future[T]` and you are providing `Option[Unit]`

Though sometimes, for code tidiness you would want to have a single `for` loop with many such expressions. In those cases you could:

```
 scala> implicit def toFuture[T](t: => T):Future[T] = {
     | val p = Promise[T]()
     | p.tryComplete(Try(t))
     | p.future
     | }

scala>  for {
     |          opt <- res
     |          r <- opt
     |       }  yield {print(!r)}

false
```

The above produces:

```
res.flatMap[Option[Unit]](((opt: Option[Boolean]) => 
            toFuture[Option[Unit]](opt.map[Unit](((r: Boolean) => print(!r))))))
```

Edit: Though you need to take all the pain if you are using `yield`. If you do not wish to use `for` comprehension as an expression, then you can do as you desired:

```
scala> val i = Future(Some(true))
i: scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Boolean]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6b24a494

scala>   val j = Option(1)
j: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala>   val k = Right(1).right
k: scala.util.Either.RightProjection[Nothing,Int] = RightProjection(Right(1))

scala>   
     |   for{
     |     x <- i
     |     y <- j
     |     z <- k
     |   }{
     |     println(i,j,k)
     |   }

(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6b24a494,Some(1),RightProjection(Right(1)))
```

This way no implicit is required. As compiler uses `foreach` at every junction. `-Xprint:typer` gives:

```
i.foreach[Unit](((x: Option[Boolean]) => 
     j.foreach[Any](((y: Int) => 
         k.foreach[Unit](((z: Int) =>    println(scala.this.Tuple3.apply[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Boolean]], Option[Int], Either.RightProjection[Nothing,Int]](i, j, k))))))))
  }
```

Comment: So the implicit converts it to: 

`res.flatMap(opt => Future(opt.map(r => Future(print(!r))))`

is there a **for** version of that without the implicit? I can't think of one.